# How to stop IntelliJIDEA from getting focus on macOS

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Since a few days, IntelliJIDEA from time to time gets focus while working in other apps and it suddenly "jumps" in front of any other application I'm using at that moment.

Anyone has experienced a similar issue and found the reason or a solution?

- MacOS Sonoma 14.0
- IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2 (Ultimate Edition)

Comment: Which versions (of IntelliJ IDEA and macOS) are you using?

Comment: Good remark @marit, added to question

Comment: Sometimes this might be caused by background tasks popup if you have Window | Background tasks | Auto show enabled in the IDE main menu or by debugger options like "Focus application on breakpoint" under Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger. Could you please share a screen recording demonstrating what exactly happens? Have you started observing this after IDE or OS update?